# Accessing OSGi services with multiple references from JSF managed bean

Tags: jsf, osgi, cdi

I'm trying to figure out how to get all OSGi services where there are multiple implementations (references) in a JSF managed bean.

Currently I'm using CDI annotations to access services, but this doesn't seem to support multiple service references or I don't know how.

For example, I can use the following to access a service, but can only get one at a time.

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import org.glassfish.osgicdi.OSGiService;

@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class ConnectionMgr 
{
    @Inject @OSGiService
    private ComponentFactory m_Factory;
}
```

Previously, I've used OSGi declarative services to bind multiple services like below:

```
@aQute.bnd.annotation.component.Reference(multiple = true, dynamic = true)
public void setService(SomeService service)
{
    m_ServiceList.add(service);
}
```

But as far as I know I can't use declarative services with JSF managed beans.